# Como acessar a pasta "data" no File Explorer do Android usando o celular como emulador?

Tags: android, sqlite, avd

Eu uso um plugin p/ visualizar as tabelas criadas no SQLite, mas não consigo acessar a pasta "data" quando uso meu celular como emulador, só funciona quando eu uso uma AVD. Alguém sabe como liberar isso?

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar a pasta Data onde contem seu banco de dados, você precisa utilizar um aparelho com [ROOT](http://www.androidcentral.com/root), caso contrario não será possível. Se estiver utilizando um aparelho com ROOT siga os seguintes passos para obter acesso como "super user":

Navegar até a pasta .\sdk\platform-tools pelo ms-dos e executar o adb da seguinte forma.

> .\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
>
> List of devices attached
>
> 0123456789ABCDEF device

Este comando listará os dispositivos ativos e lhe dará o identificado do dispositivo, feito isto:

```
adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF shell
```

Depois acessar via super usuário:

```
$ su
# chmod 777 /data
# chmod 777 /data/data
# chmod 777 /data/data/br.com.dominio.projeto
# chmod 777 /data/data/br.com.dominio.projeto/databases
# chmod 777 /data/data/br.com.dominio.projeto/databases/banco.db
```

Após executar os comandos acima entre no DDMS selecione novamente o dispositivo e navegue ate

data/data/”seu projeto”/databases/banco.db

**EDIT:** Tenho um link salvo onde falaram que é possivel realizar um backup do seu banco sem precisar utilizar um celular com ROOT, porem nunca tive um tempo para realizar esse teste segue Link : [Backup do database sqlite](https://dbremes.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/how-to-get-a-backup-of-your-android-applications-database-in-windows/), este link não é fixo, quando tiver um tempo testo e faço outro edit na resposta

Comment: obrigado cara, só não entendi essa de perder o aparelho.

Comment: vou editar, um momento