# Como liberar os dados que ficam na pasta "data" do celular Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, avd

Estou fazendo um app onde crio os formulários à partir de dados do banco, porém não está aparecendo nada no meu celular só consigo visualizar no AVD, como faço para liberar isso?

Comment: Você quer ter acesso ao seu banco que está no celular? @daniel12345smith

Comment: Sim. Porque sem o usuário root, não estou conseguindo exibir resultado de queries, daí estou pesquisando se consigo liberar o banco de um determinado app pelo menos.

Comment: Eu respondi uma pergunta sua esses dias que é praticamente a mesma coisa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73521/10315.
Hoje se tiver um tempo vejo se consigo reproduzir o backup no banco sem usar root no celular @daniel12345smith

Answer (score 1):

Para aplicativos em **modo-debug** e **sem root** você pode seguir os comandos para extrair o banco de dados do AVD:

```
adb shell "run-as com.app chmod 666 /data/data/com.app/databases/data.db"
adb pull /data/data/com.app/databases/data.db
```

Substitua o com.app de acordo com o caminho de sua aplicação que você definiu ao criar o projeto.

Referências:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997976/android-pulling-sqlite-database-android-device